# Can deque memory allocation be sparse?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, deque

Is it allowed by the standard for a deque to allocate is memory in a sparse way?

My understanding is that most implementations of deque allocate memory internally in blocks of some size. I believe, although I don't know this for a fact, that implementations allocate at least enough blocks to store all the items for there current size. So if a block is 100 items and you do

```
std::deque<int> foo;
foo.resize( 1010 );
```

You will get at least 11 blocks allocated. However given that in the above all 1010 int are default constructed do you really need to allocate the blocks at the time of the resize call? Could you instead allocate a given block only when someone actually inserts an item in some way. For instance the implementation could mark a block as "all default constructed" and not allocate it until someone uses it.

I ask as I have a situation where I potentially want a deque with a very large size that might be quite sparse in terms of which elements I end up using. Obviously I could use other data structures like a map but I'm interested in what the rules are for deque.

A related question given the signature of resize `void resize ( size_type sz, T c = T() );` is whether the standard requires that the default constructor is called exactly `sz` times? If the answer is yes then I guess you can't do a sparse allocation at least for types that have a non trivial default constructor, although presumably it may still be possible for built in types like int or double.

Comment: are you maybe looking for reserve() ?

Comment: I don't think the implementation can delay allocating the object, because if you look into the exception guarantees of `deque` you'll probably find that `operator[]` will not throw if the argument is in range of `size()`. And also as you say at the end there's probably an explicit or implicit guarantee somewhere that `resize()` does create objects. If I could be bothered to look up the relevant quotes, I'd make this an answer :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop `operator[]` must have constant time, is not allowed to throw, and must return a reference to a valid object.  In addition, `resize` is _defined_ to copy construct the additional elements, at the time it is called.  These copy constructors may have observable side effects, and there's no special language in the standard to allow the compiler to elide them anyway.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end if it is required to call the default constructor at the point of the resize call is it still possible to have a specialization for built in types or POD types in general?

Comment: It can't _allocate_ lazily as that could throw, but could init trivial types lazily (if using `std::allocator`): the "as if" rule allows it if the visible behaviour is "as if" the standard requirements were met, but I don't think your idea would be beneficial in general. The cost of zero-init'ing a block of builtin types is fairly low compared to the extra overhead that would be needed to implement lazy-init, which would need to keep track of which elements (or blocks of elements) have been init'd and would need to check on every access whether the element (or block) needs init'ing.

Answer (score 3):

All elements in the `deque` must be correctly constructed.  If you need
a sparse implementation, I would suggest a `deque` (or a `vector`) to
pointers or a `Maybe` class (you really should have one in your toolbox
anyway) which doesn't contruct the type until it is valid.  This is not
the role of `deque`.

Comment: I have already found a "sparse array" which I am using. I guess I should have been more clear that this was more a question of whether a C++ 11 standard conforming deque could be implemented to do lazy memory allocation and if not what specific things in the standard preclude it.

Answer (score 3):

`23.3.3.3` states that `deque::resize` will append `sz - size()` default-inserted elements (`sz` is the first argument of `deque::resize`).

Default-insertion (see `23.2.1/13`) means that an element is initialized by the expression `allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(m, p)` (where `m` is an allocator and `p` a pointer of the type that is to be constructed). So memory has to be available and the element will be default constructed (initialized?).

All-in-all: `deque::resize` cannot be lazy about constructing objects if it wants to be conforming. You can add lazy construction to a type easily by wrapping it in a `boost::optional` or any other `Maybe` container.

Comment: Interesting. Is this requirement to call construct true even for built in types? If so is this for exception reasons as mentioned earlier by Steve Jessop, because construct may have side effects or some other reason?

Comment: The default implementation of construct will simply end up calling `::new((void*)p) T`, which is called `placement new`. This enables containers to pre-allocate raw memory but not construct the actual object. For built-in types nearly the same rules apply as for objects (see the difference between default construction and default initialization).

Comment: When `Allocator` is not `std::allocator` it could have user-visible side-effects (e.g. keeping a count of constructed objects) so the calls to `allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct` need to happen when specified by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second  question. Interestingly enough, there is a difference between C++03 and C++11.

Using C++03, your signature

```
void resize ( size_type sz, T c = T() );
```

will default construct the parameter (unless you supply another value), and then *copy construct* the new members from this value.

In C++11, this function has been replaced by two overloads

```
void resize(size_type sz);

void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

where the first one default constructs (or value initializes) `sz` elements.